# Divide the text input (include multiple delimiter) into separate columns by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a input in .txt format as :

[image: Input image].

Need output in excel as

[image: Output Image]

or

[image: Output 2]

Comment: What are you asking for, can you be more specific and provide some code that you've tried.

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/SC_5.txt', sep =':') through this I am separate the input file based on only ":". Other value of input file which is 0,0.1,0.2 are in a same column. This also should be separated based on ',' so that I can able to get proper output which is reflecting in output image1. Hope this help to you understand more.

Comment: To convert your input into first indicated output, simply replace ':' , with "," and save the file with ".csv" extension. Open this ".csv" file in Excel choosing "comma" as delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\path\to\file.txt', sep='[:,]', engine='python',header=None).T
```

`sep='[:,]'` is regular expression telling pandas to create a new column whenever it encounters a color (`:`) or a comma (`,`)